# What is the right approach to create multiple user roles (admin and user) in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, authentication

Currently, We are working on a project (fleet management system), we have two user roles, admin (fleet manager ) and user (fleet driver). So we want to create separate dashboards and login screens for admin and user. So what should be the right approach to achieve this? I have attached the basic user flow.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In our application, we have a similar case. We have multiple stacks. One is AuthStack for unauthenticated users and one is AccountCreationStack for creating accounts. After the account is created or the user is logged in you show one of your other two stacks -> UserStack if its user or AdminStack if its Admin. In our case loginPage is identical for User and for Admin.